# C#: How to split multiple strings into 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I want to create a matrix from users input where each row is created from string of numbers divided by space. (In the beginning user inputs size of a matrix).

Example input: 
1 4 6 4 enter 
9 8 5 2 enter 
0 3 6 1 enter

And the output will be: array[1, 1] = 1 array[1,2] = 4 ... array[2,1] = 9 etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, please post the code you have tried.

Comment: The closest I could get to was to create an array of strings divided by spaces, and than I didn't know how to divide theese strings into array elements. 

'string[] input2 = new string[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                input2[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }'

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this would be to

1. read the input
2. Split the input based on spaces
3. Convert it to list of `int` and add it to a `List<List<int>>` object.

Example:
*this code is very basic and assumes the input is going to be based on integers and spaces. You should look into adding checks to make sure input is in the correct format*

```
List<List<int>> arr = new List<List<int>>();
while (true) {
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        break;
    arr.Add(line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList());
}

// input:
1 2 3<enter>
4 5 6<enter>
7 8 9<enter>
<enter>
```

Or you can create a jagged array to access via indecies. *Following assumes 3 rows.*

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][];
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        break;
    arr[i++] = line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
}
```